# Function reduce1 in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Is `reduce1` not in the clojure.core? I am using Emacs with CIDER and i don't have `reduce1`, `(doc reduce1)` returns `nil`.

Comment: You only tagged this as `clojure` but how should we know what `reduce1` does? Can you describe this function that you're missing?

Comment: I was checking the source of `merge` and `reduce1` is used there, so i checked for it but didn't found it in my version 1.7. It seems to be added to the clojure.core since 1.8. (https://crossclj.info/ns/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0-RC1/clojure.core.html#_reduce1)

Comment: `reduce1` is an implementation detail of Clojure core. Don't use it. It might disappear and it may not even exist in ClojureScript or Clojure for CLR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reduce1` is a [private](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L895-L910) reduce function used in Clojure's bootstrapping of `clojure.core`. It is needed because some of the things that `reduce` need to work haven't been loaded yet. You shouldn't use `reduce1` in your own code, always prefer `reduce`.

Comment: What does it mean that a function is a private function?

Comment: That it cannot be used outside of it's own namespace

Answer (score 3):

The function [is defined](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L895) in line 895 of clojure.core, but marked private, and later redefined as plain `reduce`.